# how to import multiple makeStyles in tss-react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, tss

Upgrading from MUI4-MUI5 using tss-react
in some files we have multiple styles import

```
 const { classes } = GridStyles();
 const { classes } = IntakeTableStyles();
 const { classes } = CommonThemeStyles();
```

and it shows 'Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'classes'' error
is there any way to import multiple makeStyles?

Trying to import multiple makeStyles

```
 const { classes } = GridStyles();
 const { classes } = IntakeTableStyles();
 const { classes } = CommonThemeStyles();
```

i need to name each styles with different name instead of classes

Comment: You can have [named destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#assigning_to_new_variable_names).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning to new variable names

> A property can be unpacked from an object and assigned to a variable with a different name than the object property.

```
 const { classes: rfpGridClasses } = RfpGridStyles();
 const { classes: intakeTableClasses } = IntakeTableStyles();
 const { classes: commonThemeClasses } = CommonThemeStyles();
```

Comment: `as` keyword cannot be used here as it's not the correct syntax.